No animation in plotly.express linear chart
Im trying to use a animated linear chart with plotly.express on csv that has OHCLV records inside. but my chart doesn't show any lines on it.
this is a sample record:
Timestamp,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
2024-04-08 00:30:00,69271,69358,69023,69023,8.19441635
I've used this chart to show a graph of (time, high) but there is no graph
px.line(df, x="Timestamp", y="High", animation_frame="High", animation_group="Timestamp", range_y=[60000,70000], range_x=(100,10000000))
enter image description here

the issue persists; time progresses, but there's no line representing the highs on the chart. do i need to change my timestamp format...? or use other external libs?

I overlooked that you want to animate a line chart, but you can't do that with an express line chart, so you have to create it with a graph object. You can create a graph object in a dictionary format with frames from the start time to the next start time, and from the start time to the next next start time. See this reference for more information.
